# html button focus/outline behaves differently if just a style is added, at least in Chrome 83

Tags: html, google-chrome, button

I'm experiencing a different behavior of HTML button with just adding a simple background-color (for example, it could be a border-radius).

```
<button>Button with no style</button>
<button style="background-color: pink">Button with background-color</button>
```

First of all it seems that setting some style to a button, the browser changes some builtin style/behavior, I see them like this in the latest Chrome 83:

[image]

So there's not only the background-color, but also the border, but there's something else also with the outline behavior.

The button on the left can be focus with the TAB key (the outline appears), but if the button is not focus and it is clicked, the outline does not appear.

Instead, if the button on the right is clicked, the outline appears and keeps it.

Do you have any reference of this behavior?

I'd like to have the same behavior of the left button, so that the button is focusable with the keyboard and the outline is shown, but when I click it (and it's not focus) I don't want the outline to appear and keep it visible.

```html
<button>Button with no style</button>

<button style="background-color: pink">Button with background-color</button>
```

Comment: This was all from the Chrome 83 update for WCAG / accessibility. Just override the user agent styles with your own.

Comment: I can't recreate the issue you're describing. Both buttons work in an identical way. Have you tested this in Chrome Incognito mode to rule out interference from an extension?

Comment: https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html

Comment: Same behaviour in W10 Firefox (77+). But instead of figuring out and anticipating all the differences in behaviour between browsers, create your own button (even if it looks like the default button). This way **you** are in control of the layout instead of the vendors...

Comment: As I know I'm not in control to remove the focus (or better the outline) after the button is pressed (without javascript). The new version of button in Chrome 83 does that: the button is focusable with the TAB, but if you click it the outline hides. I think the spec says the button should keep the focus after pressed, but I want to hide the outline. I cannot completely remote the outline since I want to see it when the button is focus with TAB... exactly as the new version in Chrome 83 does (button on the left)